# React correct way to refresh table data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a container that returns two components - a form to add a new journey and a table to list all the journeys. The form and the table are both on the same page.

In the table I am adding a clickable cell to Edit/delete a journey. While I am able to delete a given journey, the page breaks immediately after, when trying to render the table because one of the journeys does not exist anymore.

What is the best way to implement this functionality where I can Add/Edit/Delete journeys from the same page and refresh the table with updated data whenever there is a change in data?

`journeysAdmin` Container:

```
class JourneysAdmin extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onFetchJourneys(this.props.token, this.props.userId);
  }

  renderTableHeader() {
    return (
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Description</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Progress</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Journey Points</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Journey Status</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let journeys = <Spinner />;
    if (!this.props.loading) {
      journeys = this.props.journeys.map(journey => (
        <JourneyAdmin
          key={journey._id}
          journeyID={journey._id}
          name={journey.name}
          description={journey.description}
          progress={journey.journeyPoints}
          journeyPoints={journey.journeyPoints}
          journeyStatus={journey.status}
          journeyUserType={journey.journeyUserType}
          isAuthenticated={this.props.user.isAuthenticated}
          role={this.props.user.role}
          lessons={journey.lessons}
          journeyClicked={() =>
            this.props.onJourneyClicked(
              this.props.token,
              journey._id,
              this.props.userId
            )
          }
          deleteJourney={() =>
            this.props.onJourneyDeleted(journey._id, this.props.token)
          }
        />
      ));
    }
    return (
      <Paper>
        <JourneyAdminForm
          createjourney={(
            journeyName,
            journeyDescription,
            journeyPoints,
            journeyLevel,
            journeyTime,
            lessonName,
            lessonShortDescription,
            lessonDescription,
            lessonExampleText
          ) =>
            this.props.onAddJourney(
              journeyName,
              journeyDescription,
              journeyPoints,
              journeyLevel,
              journeyTime,
              lessonName,
              lessonShortDescription,
              lessonDescription,
              lessonExampleText,
              this.props.token
            )
          }
        />
        <Table>
          {this.renderTableHeader()}
          {journeys}
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    journeys: state.journey.journeys,
    loading: state.journey.loading,
    token: state.auth.token,
    userId: state.auth.userId,
    user: state.auth
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onFetchJourneys: (token, userId) =>
      dispatch(actions.fetchJourneys(token, userId)),
    onJourneyDeleted: (journeyID, token) =>
      dispatch(actions.deleteJourney(journeyID, token)),
    onAddJourney: (
      journeyName,
      journeyDescription,
      journeyPoints,
      journeyLevel,
      journeyTime,
      lessonName,
      lessonShortDescription,
      lessonDescription,
      lessonExampleText,
      token
    ) =>
      dispatch(
        actions.addJourney(
          journeyName,
          journeyDescription,
          journeyPoints,
          journeyLevel,
          journeyTime,
          lessonName,
          lessonShortDescription,
          lessonDescription,
          lessonExampleText,
          token
        )
      )
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withErrorHandler(JourneysAdmin, axios));
```

`journeysAdmin` Form component:

```
class JourneyAdminForm extends Component {
  state = {
    controls: {
      Name: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Name"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      Description: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Description"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      Points: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Points"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          min: 100,
          max: 999,
          isNumeric: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      Level: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Level"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 1
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      journeyTime: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Journey time"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          minLength: 2,
          isNumeric: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      lessonName: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Lesson Name"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      lessonShortDescription: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Lesson short-description"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      lessonDescription: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Lesson description"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
      lessonExampleText: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          placeholder: "Lesson example text"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true,
          minLength: 8
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      }
    }
  };

  checkValidity(value, rules) {
    let isValid = true;
    if (!rules) {
      return true;
    }

    if (rules.required) {
      isValid = value.trim() !== "" && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.minLength) {
      isValid = value.length >= rules.minLength && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.maxLength) {
      isValid = value.length <= rules.maxLength && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.isEmail) {
      const pattern = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
      isValid = pattern.test(value) && isValid;
    }

    if (rules.isNumeric) {
      const pattern = /^\d+$/;
      isValid = pattern.test(value) && isValid;
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  inputChangedHandler = (event, controlName) => {
    let updatedControls = {
      ...this.state.controls,
      [controlName]: {
        ...this.state.controls[controlName],
        value: event.target.value,
        valid: this.checkValidity(
          event.target.value,
          this.state.controls[controlName].validation
        ),
        touched: true
      }
    };
    this.setState({ controls: updatedControls });
  };

  submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Create button on JourneyAdmin page was clicked");
    this.props.createjourney(
      this.state.controls.Name.value,
      this.state.controls.Description.value,
      this.state.controls.Points.value,
      this.state.controls.Level.value,
      this.state.controls.journeyTime.value,
      this.state.controls.lessonName.value,
      this.state.controls.lessonShortDescription.value,
      this.state.controls.lessonDescription.value,
      this.state.controls.lessonExampleText.value
    );
  };

  render() {
    const formElementsArray = [];

    for (let key in this.state.controls) {
      formElementsArray.push({
        id: key,
        config: this.state.controls[key]
      });
    }

    let form = null;
    form = formElementsArray.map(formElement => (
      <Input
        key={formElement.id}
        elementType={formElement.config.elementType}
        elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
        value={formElement.config.value}
        invalid={!formElement.config.valid}
        shouldValidate={formElement.config.validation}
        touched={formElement.config.touched}
        changed={event => this.inputChangedHandler(event, formElement.id)}
      />
    ));

    if (this.props.loading) {
      form = <Spinner />;
    }

    let errorMessage = null;

    if (this.props.status === "fail") {
      errorMessage = <p>Journey could not be added because of errors!</p>;
    } else if (this.props.status === "success") {
      errorMessage = <p>New Journey has been created!!</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          {form}
          <button btnType="Success">Create</button>
        </form>
        {errorMessage}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default JourneyAdminForm;
```

`JourneysAdmin` Table component:

```
class JourneyAdmin extends Component {

  handleEditClick = (id, column) => {
    return event => {
      console.log(`You will Edit row with id ${id}, Name: ${column}.`);
    };
  };

  handleDeleteClick = (id, column) => {
    return event => {
      console.log(`You will delete on row with id ${id}, Name: ${column}.`);
      this.props.deleteJourney(this.props.journeyID);
    };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Aux>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow key={this.props.journeyID}>
            <TableCell>{this.props.journeyID}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{this.props.name}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{this.props.description}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{this.props.progress}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{this.props.journeyPoints}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{this.props.journeyStatus}</TableCell>
            <TableCell
              onClick={this.handleEditClick(
                this.props.journeyID,
                this.props.name
              )}
            >
              EDIT
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell
              onClick={this.handleDeleteClick(
                this.props.journeyID,
                this.props.name
              )}
            >
              Delete
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Aux>
    );
  }
}

export default JourneyAdmin;
```

Comment: Below are the ways that I can think of:
1. Add a `fetchJourneys` call to `handleDeleteClick` 
2. Use component lifecycle methods (which one??) to refresh data whenever there is a form submit
3. Somehow chain actions such that `onJourneyDeleted` also dispatches `fetchJourneys` 
Which of these 3 is the best/recommended way of implementing this? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. It was not adding/deleting journeys correctly in my actions/reducers. Every time i added a journey to the DB, I was not adding it to the `journeys` object in the state, nor was I fetching journeys again from the DB to get the updated list into the state.

Similarly, when deleting, I was not fetching journeys after performing the delete. So the state was not updated.

Now I am doing everything from the actions:

```
axios
      .post(journeyjurl, newJourney)
      .then(res => {
        const addedJourney = [];
        for (let key in res) {
          addedJourney.push({
            ...res.data[key],
            id: key
          });
        }
        dispatch(addJourneySuccess(addedJourney[0].data));
      })
```

in reducer:

```
const addJourneysSuccess = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    journeys: state.journeys.concat(action.addedjourney),
    loading: false
  });
};
```

in Delete action:

```
  axios
      .delete(journeyjurl)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(deleteJourneySuccess());
        dispatch(fetchJourneys(token, ""));
      })
```

I also found that calling `fetchJourneys` from the container/component where I am calling the add/delete actions (e.g.: in `handleDeleteClick`), also works. So basically 1 and 3 in my comments above work.

Hope this helps a noob like me in future!